# Next without For error. Not sure why

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing my first VBA code within Excel.
basically I am creating a tool to easily compile reports for me at work. Currently I am stuck on finding the shifts that have happened between certain dates as I keep getting a "Next without For error".

```
Sub RetrieveVenues()

Dim rosterFilePath As String
rosterFilePath = "F:/VBA/on&off prem.xlsx"

Dim shiftDone As Integer
shiftDone = 2

Dim masterFile As Workbook, rosterFile As Workbook
Set masterFile = ActiveWorkbook

Dim lowDate As Date, highDate As Date


'RETRIEVE DATE RANGE FROM REPORTS

'set initial high and low
lowDate = Cells(2, 4)
highDate = Cells(2, 4)

'get row amount
With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'get high and low date
For i = 2 To lastRow
    If Cells(i, 4) < lowDate Then
        lowDate = Cells(i, 4)
    ElseIf Cells(i, 4) > highDate Then
        highDate = Cells(i, 4)
    End If
Next i

'SORT TO RELEVANT SHIFTS

'open workbook
Workbooks.Open rosterFilePath
Set rosterFile = ActiveWorkbook

For j = 1 To 5

    Sheets(i).Activate

    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Row = 2 To lastRow

        'Sort Lines
        'Sort on/off premesis
        If rosterFile.Cells(Row, 1).Value = "On Prem" Then

            'retrieve date
            Dim shiftDate As Date

            shiftDate = rosterFile.Cells(Row, 12).Value

            'check shift date
            If shiftDate <= highDate And shiftDate >= lowDate Then

                'CORRECT SHIFT - GET DATA FOR REPORT
                'display - name,state,date,time

                masterFile.Sheets(3).Cells(shiftDone, 1) = rosterFile.Cells(Row, 5).Value
                masterFile.Sheets(3).Cells(shiftDone, 2) = rosterFile.Cells(Row, 10).Value
                masterFile.Sheets(3).Cells(shiftDone, 3) = rosterFile.Cells(Row, 12).Value
                masterFile.Sheets(3).Cells(shiftDone, 4) = rosterFile.Cells(Row, 13).Value

                shiftDone = shiftDone + 1

            End If


        End If


    Next Row


Next j


End Sub
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated as I am currently lost!
Any other help with code formatting or general principles is also appreciated as this is my first time with VBA

Comment: You need to close your `With ...` statements with an `End With`

Comment: Did you close both of your `With` statements or just one?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get that error is that you need to close your `With` with an `End With`, just like every `For` must have a `Next` and every `If` must have an `End If`.

```
Sub RetrieveVenues()

Dim rosterFilePath As String
rosterFilePath = "F:/VBA/on&off prem.xlsx"

Dim shiftDone As Integer
shiftDone = 2

Dim masterFile As Workbook, rosterFile As Workbook
Set masterFile = ActiveWorkbook

Dim lowDate As Date, highDate As Date


'RETRIEVE DATE RANGE FROM REPORTS

'set initial high and low
lowDate = Cells(2, 4)
highDate = Cells(2, 4)

'get row amount
With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

'get high and low date
For i = 2 To lastRow
    If Cells(i, 4) < lowDate Then
        lowDate = Cells(i, 4)
    ElseIf Cells(i, 4) > highDate Then
        highDate = Cells(i, 4)
    End If
Next i

'SORT TO RELEVANT SHIFTS

'open workbook
Workbooks.Open rosterFilePath
Set rosterFile = ActiveWorkbook

For j = 1 To 5

    Sheets(i).Activate

    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For Row = 2 To lastRow

        'Sort Lines
        'Sort on/off premesis
        If rosterFile.Cells(Row, 1).Value = "On Prem" Then

            'retrieve date
            Dim shiftDate As Date

            shiftDate = rosterFile.Cells(Row, 12).Value

            'check shift date
            If shiftDate <= highDate And shiftDate >= lowDate Then

                'CORRECT SHIFT - GET DATA FOR REPORT
                'display - name,state,date,time

                masterFile.Sheets(3).Cells(shiftDone, 1) = rosterFile.Cells(Row, 5).Value
                masterFile.Sheets(3).Cells(shiftDone, 2) = rosterFile.Cells(Row, 10).Value
                masterFile.Sheets(3).Cells(shiftDone, 3) = rosterFile.Cells(Row, 12).Value
                masterFile.Sheets(3).Cells(shiftDone, 4) = rosterFile.Cells(Row, 13).Value

                shiftDone = shiftDone + 1

            End If


        End If


    Next Row


Next j


End Sub
```